# Map different fields of same class using @QuerySqlField on Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I have a class with the following fields:

```
class Offer {
 @QuerySqlField
 private Flight departure;

 @QuerySqlField
 private Flight return;
}
```

Both fields are `Flight`, specified below:

```
class Flight {
  @QuerySqlField(name = "flightCode")
  private String flightCode;
}
```

When looking at the database I see only one `flightCode` given that Apache Ignite flattened it. Is there a way to map `departureFlightCode` and `returnFlightCode` without creating an extra class?

Answer (score 0):

Using nested classes is not recommended because there are gaps in their support.

You can use QueryEntities for mapping of object to table, and Binarylizable to specify how your object maps to cache entry.